# Not able to see any Ad in by AdView Banner using AdMob

Tags: android, admob

**Here is my Activity class**

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private InterstitialAd interstitial;

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Prepare the Interstitial Ad
                interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
                // Insert the Ad Unit ID
                interstitial.setAdUnitId("Ad-ID");

        //Locate the Banner Ad in activity_main.xml
        AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);

        // Request for Ads
        AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder=new AdRequest.Builder();

        // Add a test device to show Test Ads
            adRequestBuilder .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);
            adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice("abcd").build();

        // Load ads into Banner Ads



            //adView.setAdUnitId("Ad-ID");
            adView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());

        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Call displayInterstitial() function
                displayInterstitial();
            }

        });
    }//end of onCreate

    protected void displayInterstitial() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
    }
```

**This is my simple XML Layout**

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="Ad-ID" />
```

I tried running the application there is no error shown and I am not able to seen any sample ad's in my layout when I run it.

Please let me know where was I mistaken.

Comment: Test id is some thing you get from log cat else for live ads insert your real app id

Comment: @Muhammad Babar thank you very much now I am able to see some demo ad in my layout by placing the following:                              adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"); And I have commented the following line                  //adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice("abcd").build();

Comment: @Muhammad Babar can you please let me know what should I do If I need to get some live ad's ,I mean can I add some ad's in my AdMob account and use it in my android app.

Comment: You need to create an app on Admob and use the id for live ads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to replace your own `Ad Unit Id` in your code and xml file.
2. `adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice("abcd").build();` Here `abcd` is not a vaild device id. If you are running your app on a real device then in `Logcat` you will find its device id.

You will have to put that id here in spite of `abcd`.

In Logcat you will get a line saying,

> To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice("SOME_ID_HERE");

You will have to put this id shown here in your code.

Comment: @Muhammad Babar I have done all the steps that you have mentioned and now I am able to display an demo add given by AdMob.Now my actual requirement is I need to get some live Ad's for example:when we take any app in play store we will see that some Ad's are show In the same way I need to get some live Ad's in my android app. Please guide me some sources to achieve this.

Comment: @manideep also check this one https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/faq#whynoads